# Connect QtWebSocket from remote machine

Tags: javascript, qt, websocket

I have a local application which exposes a Qt WebSocket Server. The same machine exposes a WebPage through Apache (on http://localhost/myBackend/index.html). I am able to correctly access the web socket on my **local machine** through:

```
new WebSocket("ws://localhost:23000/echo")
```

But if I try to access the WebSocket from another machine (connected to the same LAN of the previous one) I get:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://machine_address:23000/echo' failed:
>   Error in conection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

(also changing localhost with my local IP address, of course!)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Qt application was exposing the WebSocketServer on localhost address instead of real address.